# How to get customers feedback without declining in DocuSign?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm trying to get the customer's feedback on the quote instead of declining and entering reason.
Once the customer declined I have to create a new quote and send it again instead of correcting it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this embedded or remote?  I'm guessing embedded if it's a quote.

One option is to use the "Finish Later" button.  Then set a specific url route back to your app (Features -> Branding -> edit -> Landing Pages) such that that landing page within your app says something like "We see you had an issue with signing your quote.  Please tell us how we can help" and provide the choices there.  Continue processing based on their choice.

Though I'll say I don't think there's anything wrong with declining and re-creating after they correct the input.  May be cleaner and easier that way.

Comment: I believe you can also customize the 'help & support' URL and display text available during signing to do something similar. The 'finish later' display text could also be customized too. Btw, nice idea here reinkesm.